# Rename tag in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
<entry key="name">sam</entry>
</properties>
```

I want to modify the key value(key="user" to key="id") using xslt, the output xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="id">1234</entry>
<entry key="call">sam</entry>
</properties>
```

Could someone please help me with this? As I am very new to this XSLT area.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to first transform this with identity transform than handle key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@key[. = 'user']">
        <xsl:attribute name="key">id</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Rupesh. I am getting the below error when i run the XSLT.
I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:

Comment: which application you are using for conversion.

Comment: i am using Saxon jar, This is the java code i am using:
`code`
public class Temp implements Serializable {
 static String inputFile = "D:\\file.xml";
 static String templateFile = "D:\\temp.xsl";
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

         String[] arglist = {inputFile, templateFile};

         Transform.main(arglist);

     }
 
 
}